# Is reverse proxy considered as a form of “public mirror”?

Tags: internet, intellectual-property, licensing

The Anaconda repo states that:

> Public mirrors of this are not allowed without express permission from Anaconda, Inc.

If someone builds a public reverse proxy to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/ , is it considered as a violation of terms above?

A reverse proxy is a service that does not store upstream packages on a local disk like a mirror server, instead, every time a user requests a package from reverse proxy, the proxy server fetches it just in time from upstream and send it back to the user. From the users perspective, it behaves just like a mirror with more delays. However, reverse proxy is also broadly used in public networks.

For more details, https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4471/agpl-violation-using-reverse-proxy is probably a good explanation.

Comment: Is a public reverse proxy like a mirror?  We need slightly more explanation, I think.  This isn't Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

To be considered a "public mirror", a service would need to store and make available the same files that are upstream, thus mirroring the files.

A reverse proxy is just another point to access where the files are stored but doesn't actually store any files.